# Adding a Button - how to?

Tags: android

[image: look for view and sort button]
How can I add view and sort button on scrollable listview

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far. This is not a coding service, so we are not going to write the full solution for you. Thanks for understanding.

Comment: Thank you for reply, Sir i have created the whole UI as shown in picture, I just want to add the two buttons on listview, I just need a hint i.e type of button or just tiny explanation that what should i try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add two buttons into your layout as per the image, you have uploaded into your question, then you can use Relative layout as your main layout into XML.

Then into Relative layout, use Linear Layout that contains only top filer, top two buttons and list view.

And then add second Linear Layout into your main relative layout below the First linear layout. This second Linear layout contains your two buttons view and Filter.

It will look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!--  here your top search bar comes -->
        <!--  here your horizontal layout with two buttons Rent and Buy are comes.-->
        <!--  here your list or recycler view comes-->

    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- This below layout contains the two button which you want to add as per your question. -->
    <!-- You can add the background or style to layout and buttons as your wish. -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="View" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Sort" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```